# How do I set selected tab in UITabBarController using StoryBoard?

Tags: ios, tabs, uistoryboard

How can I switch to some tab in `UITabBarController` using StoryBoard? I have tried the code below but without success (the tab is not selected):

```
self.tabBar.selectedIndex = 3;
```

Honestly I used nib files without StoryBoard and this code above worked fine in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
          :(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

but now I can't set the tab programatically. Maybe there is another problem that is not connected to selecting the tab. How can I switch tabs?

Comment: When you say "without success", what exactly do you mean? Compiler error? Is the tab not getting selected?

Comment: oh, thanks it's very important comment. Yes the tab not getting selected.

Comment: What about setSelected... So like this [self.tabBar setSelectedIndex:3];

Comment: @Yanchi yes I have tried it

Comment: Ok then, maybe posting more of your code would be helpful, are you doing this in appdelegate or actually in some controller that is "in" your tab bar? It seems like you are not working with "correct" tab bar

Comment: yes, I am doing it in app delegate.

Comment: Ok, how do you initialize your tab bar?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Grab your instance of `UITabBarController` then set the `selectedViewController` property:

```
yourTabBarController.selectedViewController=[yourTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3];//or whichever index you want
```

Answer (score 18):

Alexander, I think your problem is getting correct instance of your tab bar. If your tab bar is your root view controller, then you can do it like this in your appdelegate if didFinishLoading method:

```
UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    [tabBar setSelectedIndex:3];
```

Give it a try and tell me the result please.

Comment: *Swift Comment - 18 months later if you convert this into Swift in your appDelegate as shown above you'll get the expected result. The Swift translation is:

    `let tabBar: UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as!     UITabBarController`

Answer (score 12):

*Swift Comment - 18 months later if you convert Yanchi's solution into Swift in your appDelegate you'll get the expected result. The Swift translation is:

```
let tabBar: UITabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController

tabBar.selectedIndex = 1
```

Comment: Thank you Space Monkey. May your ship land safely.

Comment: Thanks saved my day.

Answer (score 4):

This will work in stroryboard too...

`[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];` with this add `UITabBarControllerDelegate` in `.h`

and then use this `delegate` method

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)theTabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    return (theTabBarController.selectedViewController != viewController);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4.1

In your `TabBarViewController` class, you can add this key line

```
self.selectedIndex = 0
```

Comment: best approach! Used this and everything went fine!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this also using storyboards only. Ctrl-drag from the tabBarController to your ViewController(s), and select 'Relationship Segue, View controllers'. The first ViewController you select will be the default/initial ViewController.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using IBInspected in `LSwift`:

```
extension UITabBarController {
    @IBInspectable var selected_index: Int {
        get {
            return selectedIndex
        }
        set(index) {
            selectedIndex = index
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.3**

Let `tabBar` be an instance of `UITabBarController` then :

```
tabBar.selectedViewController = tabBar.viewControllers![2]
```

**Note:**
Instead of 2, put your desired viewController's index

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I do (Swift 5.x):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        if let tabBarController = self.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
            if let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = tabBarController.viewControllers {
                tabBarController.selectedIndex = viewControllers.count-1
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also set the default tab in ["User Defined Runtime Attributes"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6igW.png) using storyboard.

Select your Tab Bar Controller from storyboard, in the right pane select Identity Inspector and add an attribute:

```
Key Path : selectedIndex
Type     : Number
Value    : 2 ( whatever number you want )
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `Failed to set (selectedIndex) user defined inspected property on (UITabBarController): Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/containers/Bundle/Application/545DB208-EDB5-425C-A122-618211E28C2F/MyApp.app> (loaded)' with name 'uoQ-bc-deq-view-KB6-1F-DjW'`