# When i click a button in one viewcontroller ,i want to go to other tapbarviewcontroller

Tags: ios

When I click a button in one viewcontroller ,I want to go to other tapbarviewcontroller

1. I have a tap-bar view controller name "my view" with navigation controller
2. I have button in that "my view" 
   when I click on button I want to go to public tap-bar view controller

error I am getting is:

when i click on the button its navigating to public view controller but the tap-bar is in the same position in "my view"
 help me thanks in advance

Comment: please elaborate your question

Comment: ya i have a tapbar view controller in that view i have button when i click on that button i want to go to other tabbarbarview controller

Comment: you mean go to other tab in your tabbarViewController?

Comment: see i will tell u clearly--i have a two tab bar view controller name with myview and public,i have put a button in myview controller when i click on that button it directly want to go to publictabbar the tab bar must b change

Comment: yes with my button @HuyNghia

Comment: see [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17919302/how-do-i-set-selected-tab-in-uitabbarcontroller-using-storyboard)

Comment: yourTabBarController.selectedViewController=[yourTabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3] mean i have to write this code in button action @HuyNghia

Comment: [self.tabbarController setSelectedIndex: tabIndexYouWantTogo]; see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676718/how-can-i-programmatically-set-selected-tab-of-uitabbarcontroller-while-also-tri)

Comment: thxq for helping me frds..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here if you have a tabBarController with say 3 View controllers.
you are at the first View controller and you click a button which will take you to the 2nd view controller. Write this code in the Action method of the Button

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1; //1 is the index of the array which is self.tabBarController.viewControllers.
```

Tabbar controller contains its root view controllers as an array which you can get if you print

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers
```

So accessing for accessing any view controller you have to know its index set it as the tabBarController's selected index.

Hope this helps