# Swift - How do I segue with a button from ViewController to a specific TabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

From a ViewController before a TabBarController in Swift, I would like to send to a specific Tab after the TabBarController that may be a NavigationController or a simple ViewController.

For the moment I make like this:

```
@IBAction func settingsButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 3 // 4d tab
        performSegueWithIdentifier("tabBarShow", sender: self)
}
```

With this action, it performs the segue but it always show the first tab.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is it possible that the TabBarVC has no selectedIndex because you're performing the action on the tabBarController of the VC that triggers the segue?

Comment: Hello @Martijn the VC that triggers the segue is before the TabBarVC.

Comment: Are you sure that tabBarController exists (not nil) and that it's the same tabbarcontroller your segue will move to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if(segue.identifier == "tabBarShow"){
        if let tabVC = segue.destinationViewController as? UITabBarController{
            tabVC.selectedIndex = 3
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Manuel it works. Even if it is a little bit wired that i have to make several segue from a VC to TabVC to manage each button which send to the specific TAB

Answer (score 1):

You can try set the `selectedViewController` property instead of the `selectedIndex`:

```
tabBarController.selectedViewController = tabBarController.viewControllers![2]
```

This person had the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17919837/3933375

**EDIT**
This is on the assumption that the `tabBarController` has been initialised, if not you'll need to initialise it first.

Comment: Hello Ollie. you mean with initialise that i have to put the name "tabBarController"(Storyboard ID) in the .storyboard?

Comment: Yes that's correct, and when you want to use it you can initialise it like this: `let tabBarController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarController") as! UITabBarController`

Comment: Thank You @Ollie. I will still with the prepareForSegue solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the selected index before the TabbarController is loaded , so store your selected index somewhere , and set this in TabBarViewController's ViewDidLoad.

self.selectedIndex = valueOFSelectedIndexStored;